# Python If statement doesn't return boolean but object

Tags: python

I have a problem. I have the following code:

```
strCommand = "There is a 20% chance that I fail the test"

# Splits command in words
words = nltk.word_tokenize(strCommand)
    
#Add tags to words
word_tags = nltk.pos_tag(words)

if (word for (word, pos) in word_tags if(pos[:2] == 'CD')):
    value = [word for (word, pos) in word_tags if(pos[:2] == 'CD')][0]
else:
    value = ""
```

This code splits the sentence into words and uses NLTK tagging, to know what type of word each word is. Then I want to ask if there is a word from the type CD (Cardinal Digit), if so... Then set the value to that word. Now when there is a number in my sentence, the code works, but when there isn't a number in it, it crashes because the array is empty where I set the value. I thought the code couldn't get there if it didn't found a number, but apparently the if statement doesn't return true or false.

How can I make it, that it does return true or false, so I won't enter the if?

Comment: The expression in your if-statement is a generator expression. Generator expressions are truthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need just first entry, you can use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) with generator:

```py
value = next((word for (word, pos) in word_tags if(pos[:2] == 'CD')), "")
```

It will return empty string if generator is empty. Also it's quite more effective, because you don't need to build whole list in memory twice, `next()` will stop iterating on first value returned. This means it stops when the first CD is found!

Comment: But what if there are multiple CD are found?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk, exactly this statement will skip *(not skip, just won't consume)* them as you do in code example you provided.

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk, btw, your generator expression contains redundant parentheses (here: `(word, pos)` and here: `(pos[:2] == 'CD')`). Also there's [`str.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) which does exactly what you implemented using slicing. So "beautified" version of your generator will be: `word for word, pos in word_tags if pos.startswith('CD')`.

Answer (score 1):

You should simplify your if-check. Right now, you're doing the the if-check on a generator expression:

```
(word for (word, pos) in word_tags if(pos[:2] == 'CD'))
```

Which is not what you want to do.

The simplest way to do what you want would be something like this:

```
reqd_words = [word for (word, pos) in word_tags if(pos[:2] == 'CD')]
if reqd_words:
    value = reqd_words[0]
else:
    value = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression in your if-statement is a generator expression. Generator expressions are truthy. If you want to check if a condition holds for any item in a sequence, use `any(condition for element in sequence)`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any